# Ruby - Simple Text Processing - Deleting rows with matching colums

Tags: ruby, arrays, text

a quick and simple one.. I have a text file that I need to clean up ...

Here is the input array

```
[["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"]]
```

Desired Output array

```
 [["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
  ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"]]
```

How shall I go about it with simple code... delete the duplicate rows with columns [0..4] matching with the rest of the array. Cheers

Comment: In your desired output, do you want `"Time1"` or `"Time_1"`? `"Time1"` is not part of your original Array?

Comment: Question is unclear. Where does `"Time1"` come from?

Comment: apologies guys ... it was a typo (missing underscore)

Comment: @conlon Don't worry about it :) It was just a bit unclear. I thought it was a typo but other people starting saying the output of my answer was wrong. Anyway, it's cleared up now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a block to [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to specify which attributes to look at. So in order to remove any duplicates based on the first 5 columns only you can do the following:

```
input = [["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"]]

input.uniq { |e| e[0..4] }
# [
#   ["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
#   ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"]
# ]
```

Comment: Eh! This does not give `Time1` instead it gives `Time_1`

Comment: @Bala did you downvote? `"Time1"` is not part of the original Array. I did assume that was a typo by the OP?

Comment: Probably a typo. No I didn't downvote. Afterall, SO is a learning place not a regulatory place.

Comment: +1. "Time_1" vs "Time1"?  That's a detail that can be dealt with.  A down vote for that?  Bizarre!

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it:

```
arr.map { |e| e[0..-2] << "Time1" }.uniq
```

or

```
arr.map { |e| e[0..-2] }.uniq.map { |e| e << "Time1" }
```

Comment: hi Cary, does it still work if Time_1 itself is unique?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `Time_1` being "unique", as all of the elements of the array are strings (i.e., there is no variable `Time_1`).  In any event, `e[0..-2]` chops off that attribute in each row, and appending an identical element (the string "Time1") to each "row" does not affect which rows are retained when `uniq` is applied.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Set class to handle this issue.

here is my solution:

```
require 'set'

a = [["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"],
 ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"]]

s = Set.new
a.delete_if { |x| s.size == s.add(x[0..4]).size }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **uniq { |item| ... } → new_ary**. I am explaining by example:

```
a = [["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
    ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
    ["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"],
    ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"]]

a.uniq {|s| s[0] && s[1] }
# => [["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"], ["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1",   "app1", "IN", "Time_1"]]
```

For more information you can see http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html.

Answer (score -1):

```
   a = [["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_1"],
["10/10/2013", "u1", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"],
["10/10/2013", "u2", "m1", "app1", "IN", "Time_2"]]
a.uniq {|s| s[0..1] }
```

Comment: How does this differ from other answers and why does this work?